# Same betti numbers as $\Bbb{CP}^n$

Tags: complex-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables

I am sure that there is an answer out there for the following question. If one is given an n dimensional Kahler manifold $X$ with Betti numbers that are the same as in the case of $\Bbb{CP}^n$, then is $X$ holomorphically diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{CP}^n$? This is of course true in the one dimensional case, but other then that I am clueless. If this is textbook stuff that I might have missed, references will be appreciated :).

Comment: Even when $n=2$ there are 20-something isomorphism classes of smooth projective algebraic surfaces with the same Betti numbers as $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Look up "fake projective planes" and "fake projective spaces".

Comment: There are in fact exactly $100$ such surfaces (due to Prasad and Yeung); the first such was constructed by Mumford. They also have some results for $n>2$.

Comment: Oops, I read a mathscinet review too hastily.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the fake projective planes have torsion in homology, although this won't be detected by betti numbers. 


Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear Common Crane,

let me list several results and question going in the direction of your intuition
(all the information below I learned from Sergey Galkin)

1) Theorem. Hirzebruch-Kodaira, Yau.  A Kahler manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb CP^n$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb CP^n$. There is a nice exposition of this result by Valentino Tossati: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~tosatti/cpn.pdf

2) There is a question of Wilson:

*If $V$ is a complex projective manifold of even dimension $n>k(V)$ and which has the same rational cohomology as $P^n$, is $V$ isomorphic to $P^n$?*

3) In dimension 3 there are "four" complex projective manifolds with same Betti numbers as $\mathbb CP^3$ (these manifolds are $P^3$, the quadric, the manifold called $V_5$ and finally $V_{22}$. The first three manifolds are rigid, but the last one has six-dimensional moduli space of deformations).

4) Finally you can find some interesting recent development related to the question 
in the preprint  http://member.ipmu.jp/sergey.galkin/papers/ipmu-11-0100.pdf
where you will as well find references for articles in 1), 2).